# Base 64 from Nodejs using oracledb to query blob data returns empty buffer

Tags: node.js, blob, node-oracledb

blob contents - 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

```
    const chainNumber = req.params.chainNumber;

    try {
        connection.execute(
        `select logo
        from chain_logos
        where chain_id = :1`,
        [chainNumber], {
            outFormat: oracledb.ARRAYBUFFER
        },
        async function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                return;
            }
            connection.close();

            const data = result.rows.map(row => ({
                logo: Buffer.from(row[0]).toString('base64'),
                logo2: Buffer.from(row[0], 'base64'),
                logo3: row[0]
            }))
            return res.send({ data });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
        return res.send(`error returning chain logo`);
    }
```

I'm only seeing an empty buffer returned from the code even though there is blob data:
{"data":[{"logo":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==","logo2":{"type":"Buffer","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},"logo3":{"_readableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":16384,"buffer":{"head":null,"tail":null,"length":0},"length":0,"pipes":[],"flowing":null,"ended":false,"endEmitted":false,"reading":false,"sync":true,"needReadable":false,"emittedReadable":false,"readableListening":false,"resumeScheduled":false,"errorEmitted":false,"emitClose":true,"autoDestroy":true,"destroyed":false,"errored":null,"closed":false,"closeEmitted":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","awaitDrainWriters":null,"multiAwaitDrain":false,"readingMore":false,"decoder":null,"encoding":null},"_events":{},"_eventsCount":1,"_writableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":16384,"finalCalled":false,"needDrain":false,"ending":false,"ended":false,"finished":false,"destroyed":false,"decodeStrings":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","length":0,"writing":false,"corked":0,"sync":true,"bufferProcessing":false,"writecb":null,"writelen":0,"afterWriteTickInfo":null,"buffered":[],"bufferedIndex":0,"allBuffers":true,"allNoop":true,"pendingcb":0,"prefinished":false,"errorEmitted":false,"emitClose":true,"autoDestroy":true,"errored":null,"closed":false},"allowHalfOpen":true,"offset":1,"_isActive":false,"_parentObj":{"_rowCache":[],"_processingStarted":false,"_convertedToStream":false,"_allowGetRowCall":false,"_isActive":false,"_parentObj":{"_events":{},"_eventsCount":1,"_dbObjectClasses":{},"_requestQueue":[],"_inProgress":true,"_pool":{"_events":{},"_eventsCount":2,"_queueTimeout":60000,"_queueMax":500,"_enableStatistics":false,"edition":"","events":false,"externalAuth":false,"homogeneous":true,"user":...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, check the [doc](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html) and [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples).

By default LOBS will return as objects that you can stream from, or can call [`getData()`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#lobgetdata) on.

If your LOBs are 1 GB or less, then you may want to force all LOBs to be returned as Strings or Buffers.  Set these at the top of your code:

```
oracledb.fetchAsString = [ oracledb.CLOB ];
oracledb.fetchAsBuffer = [ oracledb.BLOB ];
```

Read the doc on [Working with CLOB, NCLOB and BLOB Data](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#lobhandling) for more detail.

The [`outformat`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propdboutformat) property refers to whether rows are represented by arrays or JS objects.  There is no predefined constant `oracledb.ARRAYBUFFER`.  Or maybe you added this constant yourself?